# image view Shared preferences

Tags: android, imageview, sharedpreferences

I'm newbie in android. My question is how to set shared preferences in image view. I want to shared the image to another activity. Please help me because I'm stocked on it.. Please help me the explain me clearly and codes. Thank you.

Comment: Is what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041575/android-how-can-i-transfer-imageview-from-one-activity-to-another-activity/18041651#18041651

Answer (score 0):

The "standard" way to share data across Activities is usign the putExtraXXX methods on the intent class. You can put the image path in your intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyClassA.class);
intent.putExtra(MyClassA.IMAGE_EXTRA, imagePath);
startActivity(intent);
```

And you retrieve it and open it in your next Activity:

```
String filePath = getIntent().getStringExtra(MyClassA.IMAGE_EXTRA);
```

Here is an implementation of a function that opens and decodes the image and return a Bitmap object, notice that this function requires the image to be located in the assets folder:

```
private Bitmap getImageFromAssets(String assetsPath,int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

    InputStream istr;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    try {
        istr = assetManager.open(assetsPath);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr, null, options);
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr, null, options);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```