# Image view shared preferences in android

Tags: android, imageview, sharedpreferences

I'm newbie in android please help me to my problem about image view shared preferences. My problem is how to set and get and image view from one activity to another activity.

Comment: possible duplicate of [image view Shared preferences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18049513/image-view-shared-preferences)  Please don't repeat questions.

Answer (score 4):

*My problem is how to set and get and image view from one activity to another activity.*

The Solution of your problem is following :

In your first Activity

Convert the `ImageView` into `Bitmap`

```
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
```

In second Activity

```
Intent intent;
intent=getIntent();

Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```

Then simply display bitmap in your  `ImageView`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sir, can I ask a question. Sir, there's an error in intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage")

Comment: @JaemarvParba try to use getExtra("BitmapImage");

Comment: Updated My Post Please Have a look

Comment: @JaemarvParba marv Parba does it helped you if so then mark it rite so that it can help other having similar issue

Answer (score 2):

You can do it many way . Here I am showing two way to do this.
1. Use image path in first activity and then sent the same Image path in second activity. Here is the code.

```
Intent secondActivity =new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
secondActivity.putExtra("imagePath", filePath);
```

And get the path in another activity

```
String Imgpath = getIntent().getStringExtra("imagePath");
```

Use this path to show same image in ImageView. 
2nd Way:-
You get Image in your Activity as a Bitmap and you also pass that to another Activity as Bitmap  with Intent.putExtra() like this:-

```
Intent secondintent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
secondintent.putExtra("bmp_Image", bmp);
```

and get Image  from second Activity like this :

```
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("bmp_Image");
```

Hope this Help You.

Comment: Thanks sir. Sir, same method in another activity? because I have 4 activity. Sir, how to shared in many activity?

Comment: then save image Url in Shared Preference and then use it for all activity.

Comment: Thanks. Sir, can I ask a question. My problem is if you go back to the main activity the current image didn't save. why was that??? why didn't save the current image???  It save the default image if you go back the activity...